# Sending json data through curl/urllib2 to Pyramid application does not give a proper request.POST

Tags: python, json, curl, request, pyramid

I'm currently testing out creating a RESTful json API, and in the process I've been testing out posting data via curl primarily to see if I can login through a request.  I can't figure out what to do even if I hack it to work, but that's a separate question.

I'm sending the following POST request to my app:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:6543/users/signin -d '{"username":"a@a.com","password":"password"}'
```

And when I see what data is in my request, the output is extremely strange:

```
ipdb> self.request.POST
MultiDict([('{"username":"a@a.com","password":"password"}', '******')])
ipdb> self.request.POST.keys()
['{"username":"a@a.com","password":"password"}']
ipdb> self.request.POST.values()
[u'']
```

So, it comes out to be a MultiDict with my json object as a string key, and a blank string as its value?!  That doesn't seem right.

Removing the single quotes in my json declaration gives the following:

```
ipdb> self.request.POST
MultiDict([('username:a@a.com', u'')])
```

Does anyone have any idea why my data may not be being posted correctly?

Update:

To be clear, the header I'm using is in fact application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
ipdb> self.request.headers['CONTENT-TYPE']
'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

What I DID find is that for some reason using the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library works when I do the following:

```
In [49]: s.post('http://localhost:6543/users/signin', data=[('username', 'a@a.com'), ('password', 'password')], headers={'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})
Out[49]: <Response [200]>
```

The fact that it doesn't work with curl as expected is still troubling though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure which content type you are attempting to upload - application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded. `request.POST` only works with the latter option, and `request.json_body` is used to parse data from a json request body.

To be clear, application/x-www-form-urlencoded is the format used when your web browser submits a form. It's a key/value format looking like `a=b&c=d&e=f`. From there you can expect `request.POST` to contain a dictionary with the keys `a`, `c`, and `e`.

Comment: Sad to say, I am using application/x-www-form-urlencoded (will add this to my original question, along with some discovery)

Comment: I think you missed my point that it parses things formatted as key=value&foo=bar. You are not posting data in that format, even if that's the content-type you claim to be using. You don't specify a key for that json value anywhere. `curl -d 'foo={..}' may work.

Comment: Aha, that worked.  I always thought that had to look like a json object.  I'll accept your answer, could you move that key=value tidbit to your answer?